# Split comma delimited parameter being passed to stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2008-r2, key-value

I am being passed the following parameter to my stored procedure -

```
@AddOns = 23:2,33:1,13:5
```

I need to split the string by the commas using this -

```
SET @Addons = @Addons + ','
set @pos = 0
set @len - 0

While CHARINDEX(',', @Addons, @pos+1)>0
Begin
     SET @len = CHARINDEX(','), @Addons, @pos+1) - @pos
     SET @value = SUBSTRING(@Addons, @pos, @len)
```

So now @value = 23:2 and I need to get 23 which is my ID and 2 which is my quantity. Here is the rest of my code -

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(ID, Qty)
VALUES(@ID, @QTY)

set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @Addons, @pos+@len) + 1
END
```

So what is the best way to get the values of 23 and 2 in separate fields to us in the `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 0):

First you would split the sets of key-value pairs into rows (and it looks like you already got that far), and then you get the position of the colon and use that to do two `SUBSTRING` operations to split the key and value apart.

Also, this can be done much more efficiently than storing each row's key and value into separate variables just to get inserted into a table. If you `INSERT` from the `SELECT` that breaks this data apart, it will be a set-based operation instead of row-by-row.

For example:

```
DECLARE @AddOns VARCHAR(1000) = N'23:2,33:1,13:5,999:45';

;WITH pairs AS
(
  SELECT [SplitVal] AS [Value], CHARINDEX(N':', [SplitVal]) AS [ColonIndex]
  FROM   SQL#.String_Split(@AddOns, N',', 1) -- https://SQLsharp.com/
)
SELECT *,
       SUBSTRING(pairs.[Value], 1, pairs.[ColonIndex] - 1) AS [ID],
       SUBSTRING(pairs.[Value], pairs.[ColonIndex] + 1, 1000) AS [QTY]
FROM   pairs;

/*
Value       ColonIndex    ID     QTY
23:2        3             23     2
33:1        3             33     1
13:5        3             13     5
999:45      4             999    45
*/
GO
```

For that example I am using a SQLCLR string splitter found in the [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=so_55942392) library (that I am the author of), which is available in the Free version. You can use whatever splitter you like, including the built-in `STRING_SPLIT` that was introduced in SQL Server 2016.

It would be used as follows:

```
DECLARE @AddOns VARCHAR(1000) = N'23:2,33:1,13:5,999:45';

;WITH pairs AS
(
  SELECT [value] AS [Value], CHARINDEX(N':', [value]) AS [ColonIndex]
  FROM   STRING_SPLIT(@AddOns, N',') -- built-in function starting in SQL Server 2016
)
INSERT INTO dbo.TableName (ID, QTY)
  SELECT SUBSTRING(pairs.[Value], 1, pairs.[ColonIndex] - 1) AS [ID],
         SUBSTRING(pairs.[Value], pairs.[ColonIndex] + 1, 1000) AS [QTY]
  FROM   pairs;
```

Of course, the Full (i.e. paid) version of [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=so_55942392) includes an additional splitter designed to handle key-value pairs. It's called **String_SplitKeyValuePairs** and works as follows:

```
DECLARE @AddOns VARCHAR(1000) = N'23:2,33:1,13:5,999:45';

SELECT *
FROM   SQL#.String_SplitKeyValuePairs(@AddOns, N',', N':', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL);

/*
KeyID    Key    Value
1        23     2
2        33     1
3        13     5
4        999    45
*/
GO
```

So, it would be used as follows:

```
DECLARE @AddOns VARCHAR(1000) = N'23:2,33:1,13:5,999:45';

INSERT INTO dbo.[TableName] ([Key], [Value])
  SELECT kvp.[Key], kvp.[Value]
  FROM   SQL#.String_SplitKeyValuePairs(@AddOns, N',', N':', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL) kvp;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this blog post...

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/

Noel

Comment: Is there not an easy way to get the 23 in one variable and the 2 in another variable? Kind of like splitting so SET @Result = Split(request(@value), ":") and then @Result(0) would equal 23 and @Result(1) would equal 2

Comment: You are suggesting the results be stored in what looks like an array. I don't think that is possible; at least not in SQL Server. If it was I am pretty sure a Google search would find what you want.

Comment: I guess you are right. This cannot be done in SQL the way I want to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to make another attempt at this inspired by the answer given by @gofr1 on this question...

[How to insert bulk of column data to temp table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570648/how-to-insert-bulk-of-column-data-to-temp-table)

That answer showed how to use an XML variable and the [nodes method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to split comma separated data and insert it into individual columns in a table. It seemed to me to be very similar to what you were trying to do here.

Check out this [SQL](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/470578/use-xml-to-split-data). It certainly isn't has concise as just having "split" function, but it seems better than chopping up the string based on position of the colon.

Noel

Comment: I would like to know why this is being downvoted. Anyone?